# Excel Help - I want to replace multiple words in a paragraph to one single world and do this for 200 individual keywords

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have a spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16XLkjZafBSSdYZaSI9LLflOMvK40WgXsbrbE7Wqcwj8/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a basic sentence about football where I've written hottie 3 times.

"Hottie has taken the top spot in the Guardian's list of the world's top 100 footballers published today. See the full list and how it breaks down by nationality, club and position. An 11-strong international panel of hottie were asked by Guardian Sport to name their top 30 players in action today and rank them in order of preference. hottie were then scored on their ranking by each panellist: a No1 choice allocated 30pts, No2 29pts and so on down to selection No30, given one point."

Now, I have a list of 50 other players (Check the spreadsheet please)

How do I change the word hottie (all 3 times it's occuring) and replace it to the football player's name and do this for 50 of them automatically using this.

Please let me know, your response would be appreciated!!!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Hottie","hottie"),"hottie",B2)
```

Please share if it works/understandable/not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did work but I have a question, how do I put this in all the columns and extract all items at once?

Comment: select the cell (not the formula text) and copy downwards.. the `A2` & `B2` in the formula will change automatically.